# Is there a blessing for boring the ear of a slave?

Tags: blessing, mitzvah, slave-serve-eved-avadim

In Shemot 21:6 the Torah states the commandment of God
וְהִגִּישׁוֹ אֲדֹנָיו אֶל־הָאֱלֹקים וְהִגִּישׁוֹ אֶל־הַדֶּלֶת אוֹ אֶל־הַמְּזוּזָה וְרָצַע אֲדֹנָיו אֶת־אׇזְנוֹ בַּמַּרְצֵעַ וַעֲבָדוֹ לְעֹלָם׃ {ס}        
[the slave's] master shall take him before God. He shall be brought to the door or the doorpost, and his master shall pierce his ear with an awl; and he shall then remain his master’s slave for eternity.

I would like to know if a blessing is made before performing this mitzvah and if so what the text of the blessing would be

Comment: bore-ei minei me-oznot!

Comment: Don't you awl-ways have to say a Beracha on a Mitzvah?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact nailed it

Answer (score 1):

Rambam does not mention that there's a Bracha on the ear-boring ceremony.

The Rambam (הלכות עבדים - פרק רביעי) codifies boring the ear of a slave, yet he does not count it as one of the 13 Mitzvos in his introduction to הלכות עבדים. So it's not a separate Mitzva, but included in how to acquire a Jewish slave.

As a general rule, we find that any Mitzva involving a 3rd party who may object, does not have a Bracha. A pauper may refuse money, so giving charity has no Bracha, for example. Since the slave may bolt between the Bracha and the boring, so it would fall under that concept.